# Solving equation $x^3+x^2+x=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, cubics

Find a solution for equation $x^3+x^2+x=1$.

I found $x=0.54369 (which is  approximately equal to Cosine of 57 degree) by

trial and error as follows:

$(0.6)^3+(0.6)^2+0.6=1.176$...

$(0.5)^3+(0.5)^2+0.5=0.875$...

so $0.5< X < 0.6$

and $(0.54369)^3+(0.54369)^2+ 0.54369=1.000002936$

can anyone gives an anlytic solution for this equation?

Thanks for solution, it could be more useful if it was in detail.

Comment: Use Cardano's formulas.

Comment: I doubt there's anything you can do that's nicer than just using the cubic formula.  According to WolframAlpha, your solution is incorrect and the correct solution is $x = 1/3 ((17+3 \sqrt{33})^{1/3}-2/(17+3 \sqrt{33})^{1/3})-1/3$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: the OP's value is exact in all the given decimals.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: But their proposed identification of it with a cosine value is not correct.

Comment: @EricWofsey: well, the value is $\cos57.0648791\cdots°$, which bears some resemblance with the OP's answer (fixing the conversion from degrees to radians). But the use of a cosine is indeed irrelevant here.

Comment: You may use honer's method to solve this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function), you will notice that the equation has only a real root.

Using the depressed equation $$t^3+pt+q=0$$ you have $p=\frac{2}{3}$ and $q=-\frac{34}{27}$. Looking at the hyperbolic solution for one real root leads to $$t=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{17}{2
   \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$ Back to $x$ the solution write $$x=-\frac 13+\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}  \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{17}{2
   \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$ which is $\approx 0.5436890$ while $\cos \left(\frac{57\pi  }{180}\right)\approx 0.54463904$

Comment: Shame on the silent downvoter.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Once more ! What is really bad is that I tried to exactly follow the steps given in the Wikipedia page.

Comment: You mean the depressed $t^3+pt+q=0$